# XMLHttpRequest javascript error

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I have here a problem with my JavaScript code, XMLHttpRequest is giving a Undefined error and I can't make this working. Thanks for help.

Here's the code:
**Customers.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Clientes</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav id="nav01"></nav>
    <div id="main">
      <h1>Clientes</h1>
      <div id="id01"></div>
      <footer id="foot01"></footer>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      url = "http://www.w3schools.com/website/customers.php";
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
      xmlhtpp.send();
      function myFunction(response){
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
        var arr = obj.records;
        var i;
        var out = "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>City</th><th>Country</th></tr>"
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          out += "<tr><td>" + arr[i].Name + "</td><td>" + arr[i].City +
          "</td><td>" + arr[i].Country + "</td></tr>";
        }
        out += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the error, I'm getting:

```
Uncaught customers.html:24
ReferenceError: xmlhttp is not defined
```

**NOTE:** I'm using Chrome 45.0V along with Chrome Dev Editor.

Comment: Typo: `xmlhtpp.send();`

Comment: which line is line 24?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo on line 9 of JavaScript

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xmlhtpp.send()// should be xmlhttp.send()
```

Correct One:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Thanks

Comment: *syntactically* it is fine; there is no syntax error. It's simply a typing mistake.

Comment: Thanks , Edited.. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
```

Have a typing mistake in your code in 2nd line

Comment: Please also indicate WHY this is a solution instead of just pasting code.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.